# If $A\times B \subset A\times C$, does it follow that $B \subset C$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

On a study guide I have the following question:

> If $A\times B \subset A \times C$, does it follow that $B \subset C$? Prove or disprove.

To me, I think the answer is yes, but I have no idea of how to prove it.

Comment: Are the $X$s supposed to be $\times$s? (Are you looking at Cartesian products?)

Comment: Yes, I could not figure out how to make that

Comment: Here, does $X \subset Y$ mean $X$ is a *strict* subset of $Y$, or could $X = Y$?

Comment: Do not change edits if your change results in strings of words that are not even sentences. More people may help if the question can actually be read.

Comment: X=y is a possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, but you must to add the hypothesis $A\not= \emptyset$, therefore exist an element $a\in A$. In the case $A=\emptyset$ is not true, take $\emptyset\times \{1,2,3\}=\emptyset\subset \emptyset\times \{1\}=\emptyset$ and $\{1,2,3\}\not \subset \{1\}$. Now take $A\not =\emptyset$. Take any element $b\in B$, then since $A\not =\emptyset$, take $a\in A$, then $(a,b)\in A\times B$ so $(a,b)\in A\times C$ since $A\times B\subset A\times C$, now we conclude $b\in C$. This shows $B\subset C$ since $b$ was arbitrary.

Comment: If you must add a hypothesis, then you have not answered the given question. So you should say: "The answer is no. However, if you add a hypothesis... ".

Comment: In any case, the solution is given. I'm thinking that this guy is not being very formal.

Comment: The way the question is phrased, it seems to me that they want most of all to want to hear "no", namely that students be aware that sets can be empty. Of course your answer is more complete than that.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $A \not=\emptyset$. Note that for any $y \in B$, Pick $x \in A$ such that $(x,y) \in A\times B$. Since $ A\times B \subset A \times C$, then $(x,y)\in A\times C$, and hence $y\in C$.

Comment: ...Assuming $A$ isn't empty.

Answer (score 2):

The above is actually false, without an additional assumption that $A$ is nonempty. If $A$ is empty,  then $A \times B=A \times C =\emptyset$ for any B and C.  Otherwise Paul's answer below works